# Remove elements from one NSMutableArray which are contained in another array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, collections, nsmutablearray

I have two arrays, A and B.

How can I remove elements from A, if those elements exist in B?

e.g. Array A:{1,2,3,4,5}, array B:{1,3}

I would like to remove 1 and 3 from array A such that array A only contains 2,4,5 after the operation.

Besides looping, is there any more efficient approach to doing it?

Answer (score 9):

You have the `removeObjectsInArray:` method from `NSMutableArray`. It does what you want.